# How to get a particular item from the cart using the item id in cart?

Tags: magento

I want to get a particular item from the cart using id of item in cart (not product id).

```
http://localhost/magento81/index.php/checkout/cart/configure/id/1/
```

I want to load using this id, **id/1**

How to get that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
if($item->getId() == 1)
{
$productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
$productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
}
}
```

In general if you use print_r($item->getProduct()->getData()) it will disaplay all the information related to product in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

$this should do the trick.

```
$itemId = 1;
$item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($itemId);
```

If you want to get the product object associated to the item continue with this

```
$product = $item->getProduct();
```